# If statement continuing when false (multiple || and &&)

Tags: c#, operators, conditional-statements

I have no idea why this is happening but here's the problem [screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wquRO.png)

i = 0 and allCorrect[0] = true. The statement says "if allCorrect[0] != true" or "if true != true" so why is it still running the code inside of the braces and am I just missing something really simple?

**Extra information:**

This screenshot is taken from a file that gets compiled into a dll and used in another project. But that shouldn't effect anything anyway.

I have tried placing it in brackets and using ! like this as well

```
if ((parameters[i] == "0" && !allCorrect[i]) || 
                (parameters[i] == "1" && !allCorrect[i]) || 
                (parameters[i].ToLower() == "false" && !allCorrect[i]) || 
                (parameters[i].ToLower() == "true" && !allCorrect[i]))
```

Comment: Code needs to be in the question, not a picture

Comment: You mean why it still proceeds inside your if statement? Am I right?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr yes

Comment: Because you are using OR condition. If just "one" of the condition is true, then it will proceed in your if statement.

Comment: `||` with nested `&&` from my review and testing there is no way that your statement will be true... Unless `i = 1` or `allCorrect[]` is different than the image..

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Please don't include the solution in your question.  Instead, post the solution as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

I put all of the conditional statements inside of if (!allCorrect[i]) so it looks like this

```
if (!allCorrect[i])
            {
                if (int.TryParse(parameters[i], out INT))
                {
                    if (_command.ParameterTypes[i] == EVariableType.INT)
                    {
                        allCorrect[i] = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        allCorrect[i] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!allCorrect[i])
            {
                if (float.TryParse(parameters[i], out FLOAT))
                {
                    if (_command.ParameterTypes[i] == EVariableType.FLOAT)
                    {
                        allCorrect[i] = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        allCorrect[i] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!allCorrect[i])
            {
                if (parameters[i] == "0" ||
                parameters[i] == "1" ||
                parameters[i].ToLower() == "false" ||
                parameters[i].ToLower() == "true")
                {
                    if (_command.ParameterTypes[i] == EVariableType.BOOL)
                    {
                        allCorrect[i] = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        allCorrect[i] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!allCorrect[i])
            {
                if (_command.ParameterTypes[i] == EVariableType.STRING)
                {
                    allCorrect[i] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    allCorrect[i] = false;
                }
            }
```